# Is this achievable in any way, I have 3 lines with following amounts -5, 3, 2. I need to find the offset and locate the 0 amount

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, offset

Excel champions!

Is this achievable in any way, I have a list of values in Column A, both negative and positive. If a group of consecutive rows total 0, I want to put a 0 in Column B in those rows. For any values that can't be grouped like that, leave Column B blank.

Suppose, I have 3 lines with following amounts -5, 3, 2.  I need to find the offset and locate them and put zero in next column. The main aim if to find the amounts which is totaling to zero. It can -2,-2,-1,5 = 0 Or -1,-3,2,2 = 0

Just like the below example.

[image: Example Image]

Comment: "I need to find the offset" What does it mean, and how it can be used? because at the end you want to put zeros everywhere. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @DavidLeal. My aim is to find the numbers which is totaling to zero.

Comment: What would you want to do with the orange -7.00 in your example?

Comment: @kevin nothing for -7.

Comment: What if the next lines were 5.00 and 2.00? Would you want to group (-7.00, -7.00, 4.00, 3.00, 5.00, 2.00) all together, and say they total 0?

Comment: Yes @Kevin you got it right.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly like this: You have a list of values in Column A, both negative and positive. If a group of consecutive rows total 0, you want to put a 0 in Column B in those rows. For any values that can't be grouped like that, leave Column B blank. Do you need to make each group a different color? It couldn't be done with formulas, but it could be done with VBA.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253432/discussion-between-ajit-kumar-jena-and-kevin).

Comment: `=IF(B1="End","Start",IF(ROW(B1)=1,"Start",IF(SUM($A$2:A2)=0,"End","")))` in cell B2 and `=MOD(COUNT.IF$B$2:B2,"Start"),2)` as conditional formatting on the range (from cell B2 to the end of the list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will alternate between 2 colours. The list of numbers should be in Column A and the 0's will be written in Column B.

```
Sub sum_groups()

Dim CurrentCell As Range, CurrentRange As Range, rg As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ColorIndex As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
ColorIndex = 6

Set CurrentCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
Set CurrentRange = CurrentCell

'Loop until end of list
Do Until CurrentCell.Row = LastRow

    'Loop until 0 group is found
    Do Until WorksheetFunction.sum(CurrentRange) = 0
        'Break loop if last row is reached
        If CurrentCell.Row + CurrentRange.Rows.Count > LastRow Then Exit Do
        Set CurrentRange = CurrentRange.Resize(CurrentRange.Rows.Count + 1)
    Loop
    
    If WorksheetFunction.sum(CurrentRange) = 0 Then
        'Alternate color
        If ColorIndex = 6 Then
            ColorIndex = 4
        ElseIf ColorIndex = 4 Then
            ColorIndex = 6
        End If
        
        'Enter 0 and change color
        For Each rg In CurrentRange
            rg.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex
            rg.Offset(0, 1) = 0
        Next rg
        
        'Move to next cell after current range
        Set CurrentCell = CurrentCell.Offset(CurrentRange.Rows.Count)
    Else
        'Move to next cell after current tested cell
        Set CurrentCell = CurrentCell.Offset(1)
    End If
    
    'Reset CurrentRange
    Set CurrentRange = CurrentCell

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that values always add up to zero, you could use SCAN to get a cumulative sum and MAP to get the `start` (first value after a zero, or first in array) and `end` all zeros in the array:

```
=LET(c, SCAN(   0, A2:A13,
        LAMBDA( x, y,
                x+y)),
     MAP(    c, VSTACK(0, DROP(c,-1)),
     LAMBDA( x, y,
             IF(y=0,
                "start",
                IF(x=0,
                   "end",
                   "")))))
```

[image]

Or if you want a counter:

```
=LET(c,SCAN(   0, A2:A13,
       LAMBDA( x, y,
               x+y)),
     SCAN(   0, VSTACK(0,DROP(c,-1)),
     LAMBDA( x, y,
             x+(y=0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry it did not work, if I have 2 debits and 1 credit number, says -15,-15 and 15 it puts the counter in all 3. This formula worked only in case of 1 debit and 1 credit.

Comment: No, it starts counting from the start and groups numbers until they sum up to 0, then it restarts. Your example of -15, -15 and 15 don't add up to 0, bit to -15, so another 15 is required to close the group.